# using servicestack ormlite, is there a way to get an execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

Using servicestack ormlite 6,4 and azure SQL server - using SQLServerDialect2012, we have an issue with an enums causing excessive stalling and timeouts.
If we just convert it to a string its quick as it should be.

```
var results = db.Select(q => q.SomeColumn == enum.value); -> 3,5 seconds
var results2 = db.Select(q => q.SomeColumn.tostring() == enum.value.tostring()); -> 0,08
```

we are using default settings so the enum in the db is defined as a varchar(255)
both queries give the same result.

to track the issue we wanted to see what its actually firing, but all we get is a query with some @1 @2 etc with no indication of what parameters where used or how they are defined.

All our attempts to get a 1:1 SQL string we can use to manually test the query and see the results have failed... mini profiler was the closest as it shows the parameter values...
but it does not contain the details necessary to recreate the used query and recreate the issue we have. (manually recreating the query gives 80ms as above)

Trying to get the execution plan with the query also fail.

```
db.ExecuteSql("SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON;");
var results = db.Select(q => q.SomeColumn == enum.value);
db.ExecuteSql("SET STATISTICS PROFILE OFF;");
```

only returns data, not any extra info i was hoping for.

I have not been able to find any sites or threads that explain how others get any kind of debug info.
What is the correct next step here?

Comment: If the difference is due to cast'ing, which it looks to me, you should see a lot of explicit casts in the "bad" query plan, the parameters itself shouldn't be needed for that me thinks. Also, you can compare the index usages itself. Just start activity monitor and run your queries and you should be able to see it. You can post QP here as well

Answer (score 1):

OrmLite's [Logging & Introspection](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/introspection) page shows how you can view the SQL generated by OrmLite.

E.g. Configuring a [debug logger](https://docs.servicestack.net/logging) should log the generated SQL and params:

```cs
LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory(debugEnabled:true);
```

Comment: we dont have a console since its a web project, but we did have a afterexec filter that gave us parameters list and an sql string. (not a executable query)
Everything looks correct there, it didnt explain the slowdown, nor could we recreate a manual query with that, which has the same issue as the one fired from ormlite.

To make matters worse since today this behavior is now intermittent, and not easely recreatable..
So after debugging for 3 days im suspecting its an issue of execution plan / cache and when we do it manually its selecting a different index or path-however i have no proof.

Comment: That's an example, you can use [any supported Logging provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/logging). Are you certain that the issue is due to the query? and not external factors like GC, networking, high CPU, etc.

Comment: BTW debugging isn't representative of normal execution as it can vary highly by the IDE 's debugger/JIT/profiling/debug symbols, etc. I'd recommend using timestamped logging to investigate runtime perf issues.

Comment: Here is what we see with mini profiler:

With enum:
`CMD:   SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM "PrintedBill" WHERE ((("OrganizationGroupId" = 1) AND ("SourceId" = 172)) AND ("SourceType" = CashRegister)) ORDER BY "PB_TimeStamp" DESC
START (MS):        100.3
DURATION (MS):    3559.1
1st FETCH (MS):    3549.3
`
Without enum:
'CMD:            SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM "PrintedBill" WHERE ((("OrganizationGroupId" = 1) AND ("SourceId" = 172)) AND (cast("SourceType" as varchar(1000)) = CashRegister)) ORDER BY "PB_TimeStamp" DESC
START (MS):        136.6
DURATION (MS):    63
1st FETCH (MS):    52.9'

Comment: Is this timing consistent with this query? Are you able to run the query in SQL Server with a string parameter for the enum name?

Comment: All attempts to recreate this manually have failed - we get < 100ms request time every single time.
Only going through ormlite do we get erratic behavior, and as i said its not consistent anymore.. it happens a lot more random now - but was consistent and on multiple servers.
For now we have made a clustered index with the timestamp (we already had clustered for all values used in where) in the hope that it will help...

Comment: If you are able to create a repro, [open an issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues) and we'll investigate and resolve any reproducible issue.